# Xamarin Forms: How to use UIViewPropertyAnimator in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to use `UIViewPropertyAnimator` in Xamarin.iOS, but my project is actually part of Xamarin Forms. I created a dependency service and tried the following:

```
var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(view);
var uiCubicTimingParameters = new UICubicTimingParameters(new CGPoint(x: 0.4, y: 0), new CGPoint(x: 0.2, y: 1));
var uiViewPropertyAnimator = new UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration, uiCubicTimingParameters);

uiViewPropertyAnimator.AddAnimations(() =>
{
    renderer.NativeView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(300, 0);
});

uiViewPropertyAnimator.StartAnimation();
```

The problem with this approach is that it's directly updating the native view, but Xamarin Forms view is no longer in sync. I noticed some weird UI issues because of this.

What's the right way to use `UIViewPropertyAnimator` in the case of Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the animation , first set its initial Transform , and don't forget to notify `Forms` of the final change when animation complete .

Refer to the following code

```cs
public async Task TranslateViewAsync(View view)
{
    var finished = false;

    CoreFoundation.DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
     {
        var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(view);
        renderer.NativeView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(375, 0);

        var uiViewPropertyAnimator = new UIViewPropertyAnimator(0.3, UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseOut, () =>
        {
             renderer.NativeView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(0, 0);
        });

        uiViewPropertyAnimator.AddCompletion(p =>
        {
             finished = true;
        });

        uiViewPropertyAnimator.StartAnimation();
    });

    while (!finished)
       await Task.Delay(10);
 }
```

Refer to https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6999#issuecomment-542488010 .